# Truth value of a Series is ambiguous when using apply lambda to check condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am attempting to strip commas from columns that I will later convert to numeric and was hoping I could get some advice regarding this error.

I have defined my columns that I want to conduct the str.replace operation on. I can remove whitespace using the same approach with no issues, but when I run the below code I get the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Here is my code. Thanks for some pointers in how I am misusing the lambda function.

```
numeric_cols = ['Doses – AZ/SII (indicative distribution)',
               'Doses – AZ/SKBio (indicative distribution)',
               'Doses – Pfizer-BioNTech (exceptional allocation)']

df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip() if x.dtype == "object" else x)
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(',', '') if x in numeric_cols else x)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a helper function as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

cols = ['AZ/SII','AZ/SKBio','Pfizer-BioNTech','non-numeric']
df = pd.DataFrame([['3,2', '4,5', '5,6', 'a,b,c,d'], ['5,','3,2','4,7','a,f,r,h']], columns= cols)
print(f'Before stripping: \n{df}\n')

def remove_comma(row):
    numeric_cols = ['AZ/SII', 'AZ/SKBio', 'Pfizer-BioNTech']
    for col in numeric_cols:
        row[col] = row[col].replace(',','')
    return row

df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip() if x.dtype == "object" else x)
df = df.apply(lambda row: remove_comma(row), axis = 1)
print(f'After stripping: \n{df}\n')

#output:
Before stripping: 
  AZ/SII AZ/SKBio Pfizer-BioNTech non-numeric
0    3,2      4,5             5,6     a,b,c,d
1     5,      3,2             4,7     a,f,r,h

After stripping: 
  AZ/SII AZ/SKBio Pfizer-BioNTech non-numeric
0     32       45              56     a,b,c,d
1      5       32              47     a,f,r,h
```

Answer (score 1):

this is also an option

```
for col in numeric_cols:
    df[col] = df[col].str.replace(',', '')
```